# linear search for a given string in java ? Are there any better solutions?

Tags: java

Sorry if my question is silly but I need some help.
Well, the problem is that I am trying to learn java and was trying to make a little program
that will search through the text file for a matching string that has been inserted in the 
parameter. I wanted to know which part of the program should I fix to make the method work properly or at least want to know if there is a better solution.

```
 public String linaerSearch(String filename,String strToArrays){
        String[]arrays;
        File f = new File("C:\\Users\\toyman\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ToyMaker\\"+filename);
       String[]items = (strToArrays.split("\\s*,\\s*"));//converting the string into arrays by comma

        //convert the int into string 
        StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
        if(f.exists()){ //checks if the file actually exists
        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f)){
            int con; int incrementor =0;
           while((con=fis.read())!=-1){ 
                incrementor++;

            char str = (char)con;
            String str2 = Character.toString(str);
            if(items[ ????? ].equals(str2)){   

        // I want to check if the string that has been passed in the parameter
        // exists in the file. But I got confused at the items[ ???? ].

                System.out.println("found you");
            }
                //System.out.println();
                //convert to char and display it
               System.out.print(str2);

            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }else{
            System.out.println("The file doesn't exist. Create a new file or use a existing file");
        }




       return "";
    }
```

Comment: Are you checking if *any* of the words appear in the file, or if *all* of the words appear in the file?

Comment: I want to simply search through  the text-file and check if the string that I passed in the parameter exists or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search for some string in a text, and do it properly, it has nothing to do with Java. What you're looking for is a string searching algorithm.

Try looking in Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

I'd suggest going for either:

1. Rabin–Karp algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm
2. Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

They are both really good and efficient algorithms, and both are fairly easy to implement.